# Energy-Momentum tensor for classical field with nontrivial boundary conditions

Tags: classical-mechanics, classical-field-theory

Question: Is there a energy-momentum tensor for the potential flow equations with a free surface under the action of gravity (ie the equations governing some types of surface water waves)?

Background: Irrotational inviscid 2d water waves are governed by the following action,
$$S= \int \int_{-\infty}^{\eta}\rho( \phi_t+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla \phi)^2+gz) \ dz \ dx \ dt,$$

where $\rho$ is the fluid density (taken to be constant), $\phi(x,z,t)$ is the velocity potential, $\eta(x,t)$ the free surface displacement, and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity. Here, x is the horizontal coordinate and z the vertical.

Now, there are several conservation laws for water-waves that are of interest, such as the conservation of mass:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{-\infty}^{\eta} \rho \ dz+\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int \rho \phi_x \ dz=0,$$

momentum

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{-\infty}^{\eta} \rho\phi_x \ dz+\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int (p+\rho \phi_x^2) \ dz=0,$$

and energy

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{-\infty}^{\eta}\frac{1}{2} \rho(\nabla \phi)^2+\rho g z \ dz+\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int (p+\rho(\nabla \phi)^2+\rho g z)\phi_x \ dz=0,$$
where $p$ is the fluid pressure.

Is there a way to derive these results straight from the Lagrangian given above, so that there is something analogous to the energy-momentum tensor for this system?

Note: Benjamin and Olver (1982) derived all of the conservation laws for this system using the Hamiltonian formulation of the problem and lie algebra techniques.